# TexWorks Green Arrow does Nothing

Tags: texworks

I really don't understand this at all....I have a latex document that was given by my professor. I try to hit the green arrow to get a PDF (which from what I can tell online is what I'm supposed to do.) Next, I'm apparently supposed to get a dropdown but I don't. Nothing happens The console gets this message

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./homework01.tex"
```

I have no clue if that's supposed to be an error message but it doesn't seem to list any error!

I'm on OSX Mavericks if it matters.

Edit: I've managed to realize I needed a couple things. I updated packages, and I followed instructions to use pdflatex homework01 to create the homework01.pdf file. Now when I load into TexWorks I DO see the PDF on the right, however now I don't know how to update it to reflect the latex. Do I have to do pdflatex every time? There's no way to have the latex on the left match the PDF on the right? Google search doesn't seem to be helping me at all I can't find anybody else asking this question unless I'm searching with the wrong terms.

Edit2: As requested, my file system. The pdf file was created in terminal with pdflatex
    README
    homework
    pdf
    tex

```
./homework:
homework01.aux
homework01.log
homework01.pdf
homework01.tex
missfont.log

./pdf:
(myschool)-logo.pdf
(myschoolAbbr)-logo.pdf

./tex:
angle.sty
bcprules.sty
code.sty
jnf.sty
local.sty
mathpartir.sty
src2tex.sty
ttquot.sty
```

Comment: To get a drop down menu you have to click the black down arrow after the green arrow: http://i.stack.imgur.com/dCdXT.png . Green arrow is for compiling the .tex file.

Comment: I guess my real problem is I can't see a PDF....I have no idea why. There's no PDF window coming up. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. The file (A folder that came with a homework assignment) came with some .sty files....do I need to put those somewhere specific? Could that be why? Then again I'd expect there'd be an error if it couldn't see it...I have no clue why there's no PDF showing up.

Comment: Do you have pdf file generated in the same folder?

Comment: @user3450598: Please give us a short overview about all the files contained in your folder. Could you please post a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) or at least the `\documentclass{}` line of your tex-file? First of all, we have to find out what engine you should use to solve your homework.
As I can see from your log-message above, you're using `pdfTeX` currently. Try to choose `PDFLaTeX` from the dropdown menu and give it a try. Is there a pdf document popping up after klicking on the green arrow button?

Comment: I don't have a PDF file generated in the same folder. How do I get that? I tried going into Word and making a blank PDF with the same name but now it just loads the blank one and doesn't use the teX file. The document class line is "\documentclass{article}". Basically this is just the homework writeup that lists the problems and descriptions, and I was going to use to help me format the solutions since I've never used LateX before

Comment: The release folder has four things inside. a README file, a tex folder with .sty files, a pdf folder with some images, and a homework folder with homework01.log and homework01.tex.

Comment: The readme said to go to the terminal and to pdflatex homework01 but that says Im missing something called "fullpage.sty" which doesnt seem to be mentioned in the tex file...

Comment: You may need to put the `.sty` files in the same directory as the `.tex` file although it is hard to be sure without more details. Does the README say anything about where to put the files?

Comment: @user3450598: Since this is getting hard into file paths and folder trees, could you please be so kind and add an overview of your files delivered from your professor? To do this you could use Unix' `ls -R` command (which works on a Mac aswell) and write the output to a file using: `ls -R > foo.txt`. This command lists all folders, subfolders and files of a directory and saves the output in foobar.txt. After running this command in your main "homework" folder provided by our professor, you should add the contents of foobar.txt to your question above...

Comment: @user3450598: Additionally, if `fullapge.sty` is not contained in your sty-folder provided by your professor, you should check whether `preprint` package is used in your document. Referring to [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fullpage), this is the package which provides `fullpage.sty`. You can check whether this package is installed via MacTeX by typing `sudo tlmgr info preprint` in your Terminal. This will run TexLiveManager and give you some information about the desired package, as well as information about whether the package is installed or not.

Comment: Okay well now I've got pdflatex working. I have one last question and it's probably stupid. Now when I load the file in TeXworks the homework01.pdf file shows up correctly next to it (I had to download packages and stuff and now finally pdflatex works.) But the changes I make in TeXworks in the LateX do not seem to affect the PDF in the viewer on on file....am I missing some step or do I need to call pdflatex in terminal every time I want to update it?

Comment: @user3450598 I've done so. The package problem has been fixed by downloading MacTeX so I dunno where it saved it but its there now. The problem is now that compiling still does nothing to the PDF

Comment: Yes you will have to run pdflatex (either in the terminal or through a suitable menu or button) everytime you want to see the changes in the pdf. If you want a system that updates on the fly check bakomatex (it is not free).

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Ah ok, I was under the impression the green arrow was supposed to compile the latex code and update the PDF view on the right..

Comment: The green arrow *is* one of the suitable buttons to recompile (if it has been setup correctly).

Answer (score 1):

Using the follwing code with `pdfTex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

This is a test

\end{document}
```

is producing an error, because `\documentclass{article}` is not defined in `pdfTeX`, as the log-message tells:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1     \documentclass
               {article}
?
```

Simply choose `PDFLaTeX` instead of `pdfTeX` from the dropdown menu. This should work like a charm and a pdf should pop up after clicking on the green arrow button. See screenshots below for more details:

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: I already had it on this, I dunno why it says Pdftex on the bottom but I do have the dropdown on the correct icon